# A drop-down with a list of week beginnings dates in VB6

Tags: vb6, date, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down box in my VB6 form, I was wondering if there was an easy way to have it displaying the dates for the week beginning for the next 4 weeks. 
E.g. if it was running now it would have,

> 19/4/2009
>   26/4/2009
>   3/5/2009
>   10/5/2009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple method that will do what you want.

```
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim myDate As Date

   myDate = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Now), Now)

   For i = 1 To 4
      Combo1.AddItem FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d", i * 7, myDate), vbShortDate)
   Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate the first day of the week, and then add 7 days.